# Python Warm / Cold Declaring Variable outside while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a simple warmer / colder number guessing game in Python.

I have it working but I have some duplicated code that causes a few problems and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

secretAnswer = random.randint(1, 10)

gameOver = False
attempts = 0
currentGuess = int(input("Please enter a guess between 1 and 10: "))
 originalGuess = currentGuess

while gameOver == False and attempts <= 6:
    currentGuess = int(input("Please enter a guess between 1 and 10: "))
    attempts += 1

originalDistance = abs(originalGuess - secretAnswer)
currentDistance = abs(currentGuess - secretAnswer)

if currentDistance < originalDistance and currentGuess != secretAnswer:
    print("Getting warmer")

elif currentDistance > originalDistance:
    print("Getting colder")

if currentDistance == originalDistance:
    print("You were wrong, try again")

if currentGuess == secretAnswer or originalGuess == secretAnswer:
    print("Congratulations! You are a winner!")
    gameOver = True

if attempts >= 6 and currentGuess != secretAnswer:
    print("You lose, you have ran out of attempts.")
    gameOver = True

print("Secret Answer: ", secretAnswer)
print("Original Dist: ", originalDistance)
print("Current Dist: ", currentDistance)
```

It asks for input before I enter the loop, which is to allow me to set an original guess variable helping me to work out the distance from my secret answer.

However, because this requires input before the loop it voids any validation / logic I have there such as the if statements, then requires input directly after this guess, now inside the loop.

Is there a way for me to declare originalGuess inside the loop without it updating to the user input guess each iteration or vice versa without duplicating currentGuess?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a need to ask the user before you enter the loop... You can just check if guesses = 1 for the first guess...

```
gameOver=False
guesses = 0
while not gameOver:
    guesses += 1
    getUserInput
    if guesses = 1 and userInput != correctAnswer:
      print "try again!"  
    checkUserInput
print "good job!, it took you {} guesses!".format(guesses)
```

Comment: If I do that though, how am I able to distinguish the originalDistance and currentDistance since they rely on storing the originalGuess? Which if I declare inside the loop will be updated with each iteration of user input